# Read a website, like a users sees it with HttpComponents

Tags: java, html, web-crawler

I want to get the html of site, like I would if I'd browse with my browser.

When I'm trying to get html of a site it comes differently from when I use chrome and I was wondering if I could make a like a legitimate get request with HttpComponents of apache.

I tried setting the User-Agent, but it didn't work..what else should I do?

thank you

Comment: Define what you mean by _"it didn't work"_.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a web page was all static HTML, then yes you could do this.  Many web pages nowadays are dynamically built with Javascript at the client from various sources (HTML, XML, JSON, etc) so the only representation of what the user sees is the DOM in the browser.  Unless you are willing to emulate the complete browser execution environment (or can hook into a browser) this will be impossible.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you..I guess if I want to see the webpage the way it is Ill have to compile the javascript stuff and everything else..